# Process of getting DEJUS rating (Brazil)?

Tags: legal, marketing, content-rating

I would like to get [DEJUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_of_Justice,_Rating,_Titles_and_Qualification) rating for [my HTML5 game](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/rotogamesq) on the Firefox
Marketplace, so that I can tell Mozilla to make the game available
to users in Brazil. I want the game to be rated as: *Livre (general)*

**Can non-Brazilian citizens request ratings from DEJUS? If so, what documents need to be provided, and in which language?**

What I have found so far:

- [Submission form](http://portal.mj.gov.br/services/DocumentManagement/FileDownload.EZTSvc.asp?DocumentID=%7bA7810EFB-09FC-40CF-A9D0-9829CB5C5BFC%7d&ServiceInstUID=%7b59D015FA-30D3-48EE-B124-02A314CB7999%7d) in English (note that there is no country field
  in the address form, and it's necessary to specify CPF/CNPJ)
- [Description of procedure](http://portal.mj.gov.br/main.asp?View=%7b6C4030FE-0A4D-46B0-BA1F-800A22C0F642%7d&BrowserType=IE&LangID=pt-br&params=itemID%3D%7B6637B075-1932-4BB2-A62C-77E5918D7CF2%7D%3B&UIPartUID=%7B2868BA3C-1C72-4347-BE11-A26F70F4CB26%7D) in Portuguese.
- [Process flow chart](http://portal.mj.gov.br/services/DocumentManagement/FileDownload.EZTSvc.asp?DocumentID=%7bAAAB0BBD-7409-4BD1-8A6D-2C9E126B27B0%7d&ServiceInstUID=%7b59D015FA-30D3-48EE-B124-02A314CB7999%7d) in Portuguese.
- [Practical guide to rating system](http://portal.mj.gov.br/services/DocumentManagement/FileDownload.EZTSvc.asp?DocumentID=%7b25A80220-B0E3-47FD-923F-246B6184C3C6%7d&ServiceInstUID=%7b59D015FA-30D3-48EE-B124-02A314CB7999%7d) in English.

Comment: +1 I had a quick look at this as well for wp7 marketplace but soon gave up :)

Comment: Great. I was following the same path as yours but was stuck at how to deal with CPF/CNPJ and how to submit the app and documents. Thanks for this great tip, and please let me know what you hear back from them. By the way, if you wish to know something about how to get the rating from GRB, please let me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My experience:

- **2012-11-26 CET**: I called DEJUS (+55.61.2025-9115), and I was
  connected to someone who spoke fluent English. Things look good:

  - It is *not* necessary to be a citizen of Brazil or to have a
    company registered in Brazil in order to apply for a rating. In
    this case, I was told, one just leaves the field *CPF/CNPJ*
    empty.
  - I asked if it is OK to submit the game synopsis in English: Yes it is!
- **2012-11-28 CET**: I sent the following documents (personal address
  hidden):

  - [form.pdf](http://sites.inka.de/klee/dejus/form.pdf)
  - [synopsis.pdf](http://sites.inka.de/klee/dejus/synopsis.pdf)

  Destination address:

  *Departamento de Justiça, Classificação, Títulos e Qualificação*
  ***Coordenação de Classificação Indicativa***
  *Esplanada dos Ministérios, Bloco T,*
  *Ministério da Justiça, Anexo II, Sala 321*
  *CEP 70064-901 BRASILIA/DF*
  *BRAZIL*
- **2013-02-01 CET**: After asking about the rating the day before, I
  got an email telling me that DEJUS normally gives no personal feedback.
  One is supposed to check the rating in the *Public Journal*, which I was not
  aware of. In fact, the rating has already been published on 2012-12-24, 
  as requested as *livre*:

  - [Entry in Public Journal](http://www.in.gov.br/visualiza/index.jsp?data=24/12/2012&jornal=1&pagina=46&totalArquivos=168)
  - [Web page for the entry](http://portal.mj.gov.br/ClassificacaoIndicativa/jsps/DadosJogoForm.do?select_action=&tbjogo_codigo=5403)

Comment: Very good answer, especially since this kind of information is hard to find. GJ!